# Overflow problem when using jquery tooltips inside of jquery jscrollpane

Tags: jquery, overflow, jscrollpane, hidden, jquery-tooltip

I am currently using the jquery jscrollpane plugin (http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/), but the problem is once you initialize the scrollpane, the container changes to overflow:hidden. I  have a jquery tooltip inside the panel but is being cut off. Any ideas?

Comment: Does this help? http://flowplayer.org/tools/forum/30/42917

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set the position of the tooltip to absolute, and then make any adjustments necessary to guarantee that it shows up where you want it.  This also means that the tooltip's parent, or some element higher up, has to have a position of relative or absolute.

Comment: no, that doesn't work. There is a place in the javascript file that says C.css({  overflow: "hidden", padding: 0 }); and only if i change overflow to visible I can see the tooltip properly. If I do that though the rest of the content overflows, so thats not really a solution.